# No visible @interface for 'PythagorasCalc' declares the selector 'calculatePythagorasValue'. What to do?

Tags: objective-c, interface, selector

I am trying to make a simple pythagoras calculator in Objective-C but I always get the following error message: No visible @interface for 'PythagorasCalc' declares the selector 'calculatePythagorasValue'.

This is my class:

```
     @implementation PythagorasCalc

- (double)calculatePythagorasValue
{
    return sqrt(A*A+B*B);
}
//Access Code

-(int)A{
    return A;
}

-(void)setA: (int)value {
if(A != value) {
    A = value;
}
}

-(int)B{
    return B;
}

-(void)setB: (int)value {
    if(B != value) {
        B = value;
    }
}

-(int)C{
    return C;
}

-(void)setC: (int)value {
    if(C != value) {
        C = value;
    }
}

@end
```

This is my AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    calculator = [[PythagorasCalc alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)calculateClicked:(id)sender
{

    double A = _ATextField.doubleValue;
    double B = _BTextField.doubleValue;

    calculator.A = A;
    calculator.B = B;


  double C = [calculator calculatePythagorasValue]










}
    @end;
}
```

Please Help!!

Comment: Is the `calculatePythagorasValue` method listed in the interface in the .h file for your `PythagorasCalc` class?

Comment: Awful formatting. And it doesn't even compile due to a missing semi-colon.

Comment: @maddy how would you include this?

Comment: @H2CO3 where is that missing semi-colon supposed to be?

Comment: @code After `double C = [calculator calculatePythagorasValue]`.

Comment: @H2CO3 thats because that line is not completed yet, I just wanted to fix the problem first.

Comment: @code Post the .h file for your `PythagorasCalc` class. BTW - if you don't know how to add a method declaration to a class's interface then you need to step back and learn Objective-C before you continue. There are many good tutorials or books to help you learn the language.

Comment: @maddy when you say 'post'do you mean #import or @implementation?

Comment: @code When I say "post" I mean update your question with the information. And I'm talking about the need to see your .h file. At least from the `@interface` line through the `@end` line.

Comment: @maddy ok I see what you mean, will upload it shortly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `calculatePythagorasValue` in `PythagorasCalc.h`.  It should look something like this:

```
@interface PythagorasCalc : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) double A;
@property (nonatomic) double B;

- (double)calculatePythagorasValue;

@end
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me about 11 error in my PythagorasCalc.m!

Comment: Sorry, my mystake I forgot to initialize the vars... hehehe. Thanks a lot!!!